# NullPointer Exception on Android Google Maps while updating Map

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I recently included [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) in my application, which includes a `GoogleMapSupportFragment`. I now get some crash reports, which I cannot reproduce on my device. The app crashes, if I want to put new Markers on the Map. Every Marker is connected with one Location, which has further informations (address, name, ....).

Here is my class which manages the `GoogleMap`

```
public SignManager(MainActivity activity, GoogleMap map) {
    mActivity = activity;
    this.mMap = map;

    initMap();
}


private void initMap() {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //...
}
```

This is the function, which (sometimes) throws the `NullPointerException`. The function `updateSignsInView` is called from a `LocalBroadcast` from an `AsyncTasks`, which receives an update with new `Markers` from the server.

```
public void updateSignsInView(LocationWO[] mSignArray) {

    if(mSignArray == null){
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,"updateSignsInView() -> mSignArray null");
        return;
    }

    resetMap();  //delete some unneeded data and do mMap.clear()

    mMarkerLocationMap = new HashMap<Marker, LocationWO>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mSignArray.length; i++) {

        //!!! this is the bad line: SignManager.java:101  
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(createMapMarker(mSignArray[i])); 

        mMarkerLocationMap.put(marker, mSignArray[i]);
    }

}


 //create a new Marker with given information
 private MarkerOptions createMapMarker(LocationWO mLocation) {

    MarkerOptions mMarker = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(
        new LatLng(mLocation.getmLatitude(), mLocation
            .getmLongitude()))
    .title(mLocation.getmName()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));

    return mMarker;
}
```

Here is the LogCat I received:

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.1
APP_VERSION_NAME=0.9
BRAND=htc_europe
PHONE_MODEL=HTC One X
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.NullPointerException
at maps.aj.bk.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.aj.bk.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.aj.al.a(Unknown Source)
at bcn.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
at MYAPP.SignManager.updateSignsInView(SignManager.java:101)
at MYAPP.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:389)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm 99,9% sure, that `mMap` cannot be `null`. mMap is setup in the onCreate() method.

Anyone any ideas?

EDIT: setupMap function

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_screen)).getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `icon` in `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)`? Where do you init it?

Comment: mmh...good point. the `icon` is loaded (from the internet) on appstart and a reference to that `icon` is stored in the `LocationWO`-Model. But if the `Bitmap-Icon` is `null`, shouldn't it crash in the `createMarker()`method? Or will it crash later, because there is no `icon` tp place at the map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is `icon` passed is `null`.

> But if the Bitmap-Icon is null, shouldn't it crash in the createMarker()method? Or will it crash later, because there is no icon tp place at the map?

Yes, it would be better if it thrown NPE directly inside `GoogleMap.addMarker` or `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap`, but it won't happen inside your `createMapMarker` unless you call a method on `icon`.

It's not possible to tell why it is `null`, because there is no relevant code in the question, but I suspect that process is killed when user leaves the application and later recreated when they return.

Comment: Hi macie, thanks for answer! `icon` should be recreated on return. I have a check-method `isAppInitialized()`, which is reloading the icons..  I manually set the `icon` in the `MarkerOption` to `null` and it is loading google maps standard icon. do you mean that process kills the downloaded image but not the icon-reference in the `LocationWO`?

Comment: Does the `LocationWO` contain reference to `icon: Bitmap`? From the code it looks like `icon` is field or static reference. You may want to update it and also add relevant code that inits `icon`. If you call `MarkerOptions.icon(null)` it should work. But if you call `MarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(null))` should not.

Comment: yeah! I could reproduce the error. thanks a lot! no idea yet, why `icons` getting `null`, but we ll see tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Android destroys your app when is not used for a long time or OS needs memory.
If you saved your `MarkerOptions` in `onSaveInstanceState` to later tried to recreate `Marker` note that icon of `Marker` is not `Parcelable` thus not saved. You need to save independently icon as a `Bitmap` which is `Parcelable` and when recreating marker do `addMarker(savedMarkerOptions.icon(bitmap));`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is see is that mMap is becoming null in some cases when an orientation change happens while your asynctask is running. In such cases when `updateSignsInView` is called, mMap is yet to be setup and so you get a nullpointer at the line `Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(createMapMarker(mSignArray[i]));`  For the `resetMap();` which is being called before this line, possibly there is a null check for mMap and hence no error.

Comment: hi tony, my app is only running in portrait-mode.

i thought about another null-check as well, but still it would be nice to found the real issue. (i cannot reproduce the error)

Answer (score 0):

did you connect the map to Fragment in the xml file? e.g mmap=findViewbyId(R.id.map); ?

Comment: yes I did. I just updated my answer. Btw: The app is working, so the error doesn't appear everytime, just sometimes..